# how do two processors communicate by a socket file

Tags: supervisord

I'm using Supervisord daemon, and I found the supervisorctl client to communicate with the daemon by the socket file:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/tmp/supervisor.sock
```

I'm curious that, how do they communicate by the socket file?
For example supervisorCtl will communicate with supervisorD with the sock file `/var/tmp/supervisor.sock`

Comment: Two *what* processors? That's just a UNIX-type socket, it's a stream connection of arbitrary bytes not unlike TCP/IP without the networking.

Comment: I understood the socket, but I'm curious why there is a file /var/tmp/supervisor.sock for the communicating.

Comment: That's how UNIX sockets are often represented, part of the "everything is a file" UNIX philosophy.

Comment: but, why I didn't see a file when I ran a Python code with demo socket client-server communicate?

Comment: What Python code? You can create UNIX "socket pairs" which aren't represented on the filesystem, but these are only shared between two directly related processes. The file-based system is open to any process.